# Creating multi drop down columns using the smartsheet api

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

Very recently a new type of column was add to smartsheet : multi drop down :
[image]

Is there any solution to create such column using the api ?

Is a new version of the api planned ?

Comment: Turns out my answer below (the one you've marked as "Accepted") is incorrect. Can you please mark **Keith's** answer below as the "Accepted" answer instead (and unmark my answer)? Doing so will make it easier for others to discover the correct info in this thread in the future. Thanks!

Comment: To add more info : I've send pull request to the smartsheet c# github repo to add the new column type and thus to be able to manage it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It is possible to create a **Dropdown (multi select)** column via the API!

*To briefly address the `TEXT_NUMBER` issue, this type is used for backwards-compatibility. If you are unaware of the `?level=2&include=objectValue` suffix, the response will return a `TEXT_NUMBER` column type to avoid breaking any existing clients that aren't set up to handle the new column type.*

---

In the following examples the double brace variables represent your targets:

`{{environment}}` is something like `https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/`

`{{sheetId}}` is a sheet Id in the form `6264126827992742`

`{{columnId}}` is the Id of your primary column in the form `2641268279927426`

`{{columnId2}}` is the Id of your multi picklist column in the form `6412682799274262`

---

**To add a column with a `MULTI_PICKLIST` type to an existing sheet:**

POST: `{{environment}}/sheets/{{sheetId}}/columns/`

```
{
  "title": "I'm a new multi picklist column",
  "type":"MULTI_PICKLIST",
  "index": 1,
  "options": ["opt1","opt2","opt3"]
}
```

---

To create a column on a brand new sheet, this example will create a sheet with a primary column, a `MULTI_PICKLIST` column, and then add a row with some data.

Then it will get the sheet using level 2 to avoid the backwards compatibility `TEXT_NUMBER` type.

**To create a sheet with a `MULTI_PICKLIST` column:**

POST: `{{environment}}/sheets`

```
{
  "name":"API PL Sheet",
  "columns":
  [
    {
      "title":"My primary Column",
      "primary":true,
      "type":"TEXT_NUMBER"
    },
    {
      "title":"My multi select column",
      "type":"MULTI_PICKLIST", 
      "options":["options","in","this","form"]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**To add a row on this sheet:**

POST: `{{environment}}/sheets/{{sheetId}}/rows?include=objectValue`

```
[
  {
    "toTop": true,
    "cells":
    [
      {
        "columnId":{{columnId}}, 
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "columnId":{{columnId2}}, 
        "objectValue": 
        {
          "objectType":"MULTI_PICKLIST",
          "values":["in", "form"]
        }
      } 
    ]
  }
]
```

---

**To view the sheet with the `MULTI_PICKLIST` objectValue:**

GET: `{{environment}}/sheets/{{sheetId}}?level=2&include=objectValue`

---

**If you do not include the `?level=2&include=objectValue` suffix then the JSON response will have  columns that appear as though they are `TEXT_NUMBER` types.**

---

*For one final note, different endpoint groups require different levels. They are as follows:*

- GET Cell History is level 2
- GET Sheets is level 2
- GET Row is level 2
- GET Column is level 2
- POST Sort is level 2
- GET Sights (dashboards) is level 3
- GET reports is level 3

Answer (score 2):

As of Oct 1, you can actually create a column that supports the new multi-dropdown feature. The documentation is a little behind.

1. If you don't yet have a column, you'll have to Add a column first.
2. Once you have a columnId, you can send an Update Column request and specify "type" as "MULTI_PICKLIST".

To retrieve the correct type when you do a GET /sheets/{sheetId} or GET /{columnId}, you have to use a query parameter of ?level=3&include=objectValue.